Power BI Visual to show category performance wrt different KPIs
I have several KPIs in my report. Is there a visual to show , how different categories are performing wrt those KPIs?
PFB sample data and the visual I would like to create in Power BI desktop.

I want to show via a visual that whether for a particular time (say year) , the category had a growth or decline of that KPI.
For ex. , the target may be £100 sales but in Yr 2023 sales was £47 and 2024 its £109. So my visual should show ,upon selecting the year, thae symbol for total sales (£) on 'decline' and 'growth' sides of the visual. And same for other categories wrt to the KPIs.
I am not sure if any such custom visual is available or not in Power BI. Hence seeking help.
